# Regex: how to extract dates with different formats and places

Tags: regex

My data would be:

```
 - List item

 - COL_DPU_JA08 Cash Remit 3/09/2017 ILA WSE
 - COL_DPU_MBTC_CJPM_03.09.17
 - COL_DPU_CJOA_CA_3.9.17
 - COL_DPU_CJNA_CA_03/09/2017
 - COL_POS_CJDB_BDO_03092017
 - COL_DPU_JE12 Cash Remit 3/09/2017 TUG WSE
 - COL_DPU_JA08 Checks Remit 3/10/17 ILA
```

How do I extract the dates and convert the said dates to this format:
**mm.dd.yy**

Comment: Alright, and your question is....?

Comment: Date format varies from string to string in your example. Do you need to match all variants or just the format highlighted with bold? If the latter is the  case try [`\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d`](https://regex101.com/r/2yVXpl/1).

Comment: First i nees to extract them and then convert them into this format mm.dd.yy like 03.09.17

Comment: Welcome to SO, Amethyst.  Please always put question details into the question itself so future readers don't have to comb the comments to get the full story.  Please take this moment to delete your comments and edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't give the language you are using, here is a perl script that does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $re = qr~[ _](\d\d?)\D?(\d\d?)\D?(?:\d\d)?(\d\d)\b~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my (@l) = $_ =~  $re;
    dump@l;
}

__DATA__
 - COL_DPU_JA08 Cash Remit 3/09/2017 ILA WSE
 - COL_DPU_MBTC_CJPM_03.09.17
 - COL_DPU_CJOA_CA_3.9.17
 - COL_DPU_CJNA_CA_03/09/2017
 - COL_POS_CJDB_BDO_03092017
 - COL_DPU_JE12 Cash Remit 3/09/2017 TUG WSE
 - COL_DPU_JA08 Checks Remit 3/10/17 ILA
```

**Output:**

```
(3, "09", 2017)
("03", "09", 17)
(3, 9, 17)
("03", "09", 17)
("03", "09", 17)
(3, "09", 17)
(3, 10, 17)
```